# Catch the absence of a pattern (Updated) following another one (INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE)

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, grep

How could we detect error cases in log files such as:

```
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,047][DbConn] - [INSERT INTO table1 ...]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,461][DbConn] - [Updated: 16282 records]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,465][DbConn] - [ UPDATE table2 SET ...]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,616][DbConn] - [Updated: 3 records]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,620][DbConn] - [ DELETE FROM table3 WHERE ...]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:22,786][DbConn] - [Updated: 1 records]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:23,723][DbConn] - [INSERT INTO table4 ...]
[DEBUG][2016-08-02 17:11:24,442][DbConn] - [SELECT * FROM table5 ...]
```

where the **absence of `Updated: X records`** shows that the request wasn't correctly executed?

In this example, line 7 (`INSERT INTO table4 ...`) should be outputted as something wrong happened when executing that SQL request.

I'm sure it's almost possible to write a one-liner for this, but I don't see the right way to begin.  Any tip?

Comment: `(\[DEBUG\].*)\.{3}\]`

Comment: Or maybe this one: `(.*- (?!\[Updated).*)`

Comment: Not sure to understand your comments...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pO4tB7/1

Comment: Please specify if the last line `*SELECT*`, (which is not followed by 'Updated'), should also be output by the regex.

Comment: You're right I should be more accurate. No, as implicitly said in title, I don't care about SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we expect `Updated` every even numbered line,

```
awk 'NR%2==0{if (!/Updated/) print a} {a=$0}' log
```

A more generic one:

```
awk 'NR>1{if (!/Updated/ && a ~ /INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE/) print a} {a=$0}' log
```

Comment: Second one does work well on given MWE. How can you think in such a reverse way (`NR>1` and assigning `$0` to a variable holding the *previous* line? ;-)

Comment: Though I don't understand why, this does not work on my real, big file where all requests were successful, but where I inserted `XXX` in the `Updated` string (such as `UpdXXXated`) to generate "SQL errors" that would be trapped by your one-liner. Any idea?

Comment: not sure.. may be just take a sample around that manually modified error and see if it works.. if it doesn't, update the question with that sample instead

Comment: Thanks a lot for your beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on regex flavor, but

```
/\[DEBUG\]\[[\d\- :,]+\]\[DbConn\] - \[ *(?:INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE)(?!.*\n\[DEBUG\]\[[\d- :,]+\]\[DbConn\] - \[Updated:).*/g
```

should work. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB9cQ1/2).

Comment: How would that have to be used in a shell script?  Via `grep`, `awk` or something else (please no Perl nor PHP nor Python...)?

Comment: Oh, you can't. They don't support lookahead.